# Do you use JSON for logging?

Tags: json, logging, nlog

I have seen people talking about logging in JSON, for example this [post](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/03/28/service-logging-in-json-with-bunyan/), but I have actually never tried it. I believe that a log file in JSON format is much easier for loading into a logging database for offline analyzing.

Anyone tried it? or more specifically, anyone tried with NLog (I saw a jsonEncode attribute in NLog configuration document).

Comment: Well, have you tried it?

Comment: I'm going to use bunyan, it's a logger for NodeJS. It creates JSON log files :).

Comment: I think if you're using NodeJS, then logging to JSON has much sense. Were you able to do it?

Comment: Yes, it's a nice logger, check it out here https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan

Comment: NLog 4 has added Logging to JSON. See http://nlog-project.org/2015/06/09/nlog-4-has-been-released.html